# cannot import name MLPRegressor

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network

Same as the title, I'd like to build a Neural Network model using Scikit Learn class called MLPRegressor. After install and compile, the code won't run and give return value: **cannot import name MLPRegressor**

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(5, ), activation='relu', verbose=True, learning_rate_init=1, learning_rate='adaptive', max_iter=500,)

mlp.fit(X,y)
mlp.score(X,y)

print mlp.coefs_
print mlp.n_layers_
print mlp.n_outputs_
print mlp.out_activation_
```

Updates: the code was running on Windows 10 with this certain specification...

Scikit-learn: 0.17.1

Scikit-neuralnetwork: 0.7

Python 2.7

Comment: This is very unclear. How are you importing it? What is the version of scikit? Which platform?

Answer (score 0):

MLPRegressor was introduced in **release 0.18** as shown [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#id4).

> Added new supervised learning algorithm: Multi-layer Perceptron #3204 by Issam H. Laradji

which links to the [MLP user-guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html#multilayer-perceptron)

As you added your library-versions in use, you see, that this feature is not available with your install. You need to update!